# Class attribute missing from DOM in inspector

Tags: html, jquery

I'm using a function to try and select a div with a class attribute that is nested in a div with an ID. The function does nothing and after some debugging it turns out that when I inspect element in my browser, the div is not showing a class even though I have a class in my HTML. Because there's no class the function doesn't know what to select. See in the following code function playBall is calling function countDown which should be selecting div.timer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Home Run Derby (CSCI2447)</title>
    
    <!-- CSS styles: This is for me to worry about; not you. -->
    <link href="css/game.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        var secondsRemaining = 30;
        var score = 0;
        var gamerFirstName;
        $(document).ready(function(){
        gamerFirstName = prompt("Please enter your first name."," ");
            $('div#content p').text('Hello ' + gamerFirstName + '! Are you ready? After clicking "start", you will have 30 seconds to hit as many home runs as you can. The images appear randomly so be ready!');
       
            $('div#gamespace').html('<img src="img/baseball.png"/>');
            $('div.timer').removeClass('timer');
            alert(numberX());
            alert(numberY());
            $('button#start_button').click(playBall);
            tallyScore();
            $('button#start_button').css({"width": "80px","height":"40px","font-size":"18px","background-color":"#b66f42","color": "#253f38", "font-family":"baseball"});
        });
        function numberX(){
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 636);
    
        };
        function numberY(){
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 350);
    
        };
        function tallyScore(){
            score++;
            $('span#score').text( score + " pts");
        };
        function playBall(){ 
            countDown();
        };
        function countDown(){
            secondsRemaining--; 
            $("div.timer").text(secondsRemaining + " Seconds Left");
        };
      </script>
    
    
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="contenta">

            <h1><span>Home Run Derby</span></h1>
        
            <p></p>
        
              <div id="controls">
                 <span id="score">0 pts</span>
                <button type="button" id="start_button">Start!</button>
              </div>
                <div class="timer">
                    30 Seconds Left
                </div>
            </div>
        

        
        <div id="gamespace">

            
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `document.ready` function, you have the following line which is removing the class from `timer` from your div, so when the `countDown` function executes, it cannot locate the `div.timer` selector.

Just remove this line:

```
$('div.timer').removeClass('timer');
```

Comment: I cant believe I missed that. That was a leftover from testing from a few weeks ago. Thanks, sometimes you just need some fresh eyes on something.

Comment: Absolutely! It's one of those "can't see the forest through the trees" type moments. Cheers!